# append(add) a text in url using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, append

below code working fine but I need to append option1 in href,

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#head_drop .dd-option").click(function () {
            var option = $('.dd-option-value',this).attr('value');
            var option1 = $('.dd-option-text',this).text();
           // alert(option1);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: '<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl();?>categories/index/city/',
                data: {option: option},
                success: function(data) {
                    $(location).attr('href',"<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl()?>");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

now its return
`http://example.com/`

I want like `http://example.com/option1`

I tried `$(location).attr('href',"<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl()?>"option1);` but failed to get, Thanks...

Comment: Try this: $(location).attr('href',"<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl()?>/" + option1);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `option1` is a variable all you need is to concatenate with a `+` -

```
$(location).attr('href',"<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl()?>" + option1)
```

Comment: Jay definitely deserves a double espresso ;-)

Comment: That would work for me this morning @Fred-ii- *Morning Ralph* (side note: we could always do a radio show, the Ralph & Sam show. Yes, I am being rather random this morning.)

Comment: @JayBlanchard *Mornin' Sam* - We could then switch roles with a quick flip of the zipper

Comment: And run the "don't use `mysql_*`" or "parameterize those queries" announcements at the top of every hour.

Answer (score 0):

You have your `"` at the wrong place, it should read:

`$(location).attr('href',"<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl()?>option1");`

Comment: Option1 is a variable, so if you put it inside the quotes, it will not work as a variable anymore.

Comment: Ah, my bad, the OP stated he wanted this URL: `http://example.com/option1`, I didn't notice it should refer to a variable.